# Some random crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS but I don't know anymore what to do.
I get the error when I try to switch tabs (UITabBar). Nothing executes according to NSLog.

The tabbar tab event is a segue where no code of me gets executed...
(arc enabled)

edit:
When I enable zombies, I get `*** -[TDAppDelegate respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e8a260`

I can press the rightBarButtonItem, the modal view is presented and just works (it also communicates with the appdelegate). When the modal view is dismissed, and I try to switch tabs, the app crashes again. [UITabBarDelegate tabBar:didSelectItem:] gets called.

stack:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x6e8a260
Alloc: Block address: 0x06e8a260 length: 44
Stack - pthread: 0xac4932c0 number of frames: 32
    0: 0x9428c90b in malloc_zone_calloc
    1: 0x9428d837 in calloc
    2: 0x1bc1c93 in class_createInstance
    3: 0x1bcc88b in _objc_rootAllocWithZone
    4: 0x17de661 in +[NSObject allocWithZone:]
    5: 0x1bcc8b9 in _objc_rootAlloc
    6: 0x66f2d6 in -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]
    7: 0x76dfa2 in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
    8: 0x76d6b7 in -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
    9: 0x66eead in -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
   10: 0x76dfa2 in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
   11: 0x76d9af in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
   12: 0x76d6b7 in -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
   13: 0x66e305 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
   14: 0x87484f in -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]
   15: 0x87499e in -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController]
   16: 0x4501e3 in -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:]
   17: 0x450461 in -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile]
   18: 0x44f7c0 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
   19: 0x45e743 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
   20: 0x45f1f8 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
   21: 0x452aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
   22: 0x1feafa9 in PurpleEventCallback
   23: 0x17b01c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
   24: 0x1715022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
   25: 0x171390a in __CFRunLoopRun
   26: 0x1712db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
   27: 0x1712ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode
   28: 0x44f2a7 in -[UIApplication _run]
   29: 0x450a9b in UIApplicationMain
   30: 0x2a18 in main at /Users/user/Desktop/app/main.m:16
   31: 0x2975 in start
```

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help you with that little bit of data.  Without code it seems even more random to others :)  I promise it won't be so random once you understand it ;)

Comment: turn on zombies - get some code fragments - something ...

Comment: that's my problem, I don't know what code gets executed... the view doesn't get loaded, init doesn't get called nothing (according to NSLog)...

Comment: The message indicates that your AppDelegate instance has gone "poof".  The most likely reason for this is that you "sent" `release` to your AppDelegate when you meant to release something else.

Comment: @DanielRHicks i can't send release, because ARC is enabled (iOS5)... sending a release would throw a compiler error

Comment: does "info malloc <addr>" identify the issue?

Comment: @bryanmac i already posted the stack generated with `info malloc-history <addr>` in the question. those stacks are the same

Comment: For some reason your AppDelegate is getting released.  (I presume that TDAppDelegate is yours?)  It shouldn't be released until the app ends, so something is mucked up.

Comment: Yes, TDAppDelegate is my AppDelegate... I don't know what causes the AppDelegate to be released... Bug in arc?

Comment: Extremely unlikely this is a bug in ARC. Can you show the code you use to switch the views?

Comment: @sosborn none, I use a segue in my main storyboard (nocode of me gets executed)

Comment: it seems, that this crash doesn't occur on device... Could it be possible there's something wrong with the simulator as installed on my mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hunch you are crashing because you don't have enough memory left. One of the relevant views or view controllers is being held because its referenced under ARC as `strong` when `weak` would be more appropriate.

Also go looking in your code for instances of `respondsToSelector:` . It might not be the delegate that is trying to be messaged in this instance. It's a red herring. My experience is that those "sent to deallocated instance" console logs rarely tell you the actual object which was being messaged.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `-(void)dealloc` method.
I was getting the same thing and in my dealloc method I was calling `[super dealloc]` first before releasing every else.
Right way

```
-(void)dealloc
{
      // Right way
      [myObj release];
      [super dealloc];
}
```

I had it this way and it crashed everytime I dismissed my view.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
      // Wrong way
      [super dealloc];
      [myObj release];
}
```

Comment: Dododedodonl said in a comment that the app is compiled with ARC, so [super dealloc] is not allowed. Good suggestion for non-ARC builds, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't gotten into ARC yet. Still trying to figure out some of the basics.

Comment: Thanks syclonefx, but as RobBajorek said, I compile with ARC. This is the reason why I think it is strange, that my AppDelegate gets released somehow...

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1**
Check that your tabBar is linked/retained. It seems to be deallocated at some time. When the modal view is dismissed, put some beakpoints to check that the reference is still valid.

**Idea 2**
Don't you have any property(copy) or variable that you are trying to [copy] without having implemented and declared the NSCopying protocol in the object itself ? If yes, don't you have some problems into the implementation itself ?

**Idea 3**
Deactivate ARC and test if the problem is still there (if you don't use huge memory in your app of course because of memory leaks that will generate).

Comment: Hmmm... The tabbar doesn't seem to be release or something.. Also, the crash occurs when the modal view isn't presented...

Comment: @dododedodonl : don't you have any property(copy) or variable that you are trying to [copy] without having implemented and declared the NSCopying protocol in the object itself ? If yes, don't you have some problems into the implementation itself ?

Comment: Nope, I don't implement any copy properties... There's even no code of me, that get's executed to select a different tab... I use the standard storyboard transition for this... And it seems, that this crash doesn't occur on device, but I can't confirm this...

Comment: @dododedodonl : what happens if you deactivate ARC (ok, memory leak is not the answer :-)  ) ?

Comment: haven't tried this one yet, because I have to write memory management code for all my code... And I'm not that good in memory management...

Comment: @dododedodonl : forget it if you do not do hardcore job. You'll have memory leaks, and what... if that works you have a way to analyse. If that does not work, well, one try for nothing.

Comment: the problem is, that I just don't know how to... I just recently started coding for iOS... I've never used memory management. And I think I'm going to reinstall xcode/simulator... Maybe this helps...

Comment: @dododedodonl: I guess that a quick search on google will shonw you where to enable ARC, so it's the same place to disable it :-)

Comment: oow, I don't have to write dealloc methods etc etc to try this?

Comment: @dododedodonl : That would be far better, but just for a test, I guess no. If you use too much memory, your app will crash, but if not, it should work. But perhaps the syntax itself with/without ARC may have to be different. You don't loose anything to try (just to try).

Comment: I tried to disable ARC, but this doesn't work, the code is way to specific to work... (I get over a dozen compile error), and I tried to reinstall xcode etc, but this also didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the crash,

12: 0x76d6b7 in -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
   13: 0x66e305 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]

It shows, the nib file is not binded correctly with the view of some particular tab.

Please check, if in AppDelegate, you are making call to the view controller with correct nib name, before adding to the tab bar.